# AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE with not working with join

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, hibernate

I have two tables name is employee and department with below structure

**Employee**

id,name,address,city,deptid,state,mobile

**Department**

id,name

Now in Java if i am firing query with join and i have set

**AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE**

it will display id column of employee table beacause of Map Result but i want all field of both table and also want result in order form.

**Query**

```
  select * from employee em left join department dept em.deptid=dept.id;
```

**Java Code.**

```
SQLQuery query = (SQLQuery)session.createSQLQuery("select * from employee   em left join department dept em.deptid=dept.id;");
query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
List<Map<String,Object>> valuesList=query.list();
```

Please help me in this how can i resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is resolved by using below method.

**Solution**

```
  List<String> clmnList=null;
  List<Map<String,Object>> valList=new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
  connection =  DriverManager.getConnection(connURL,userName,password);
  Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from employee em left join department dept em.deptid=dept.id");

if(rs!=null)
{
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int countColumn=rsmd.getColumnCount();

    for(int k=1;k<=countColumn;k++)
    {
        String name = rsmd.getColumnName(k);
        if(clmnList!=null && clmnList.size()>0){
            if(clmnList.contains(name)){
                name=rsmd.getTableName(k)+"."+name;
            }
            clmnList.add(name);
        }else{
            clmnList=new ArrayList<String>();
            clmnList.add(name);
        }
    }
    while (rs.next()) {
    Map<String,Object> valueMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for(int i123=1;i123<=countColumn;i123++){
        valueMap.put(clmnList.get(i123-1),rs.getString(i123));
    }
    valList.add(valueMap);
    }
}
```